# processMessage failed: Stack: ReferenceError: onNotification is not defined

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to implement push notification using push plugin in android(cordova+ionicframework).I wiil get the registration id in console,but `onNotification()` is never called,and returns the error message

```
09-22 11:38:46.151: I/Web Console(24662): processMessage failed: Stack: ReferenceError: onNotification is not defined
```

Here is my console output for the registrationid

```
09-22 11:38:46.151: D/CordovaLog(24662): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1046 : processMessage failed: Message: Jjavascript:onNotification({"regid":"APA91bHDLg9BZl-eicx3tS-MjVGy-mcufmbRc-EpCuKzb9b_tPddG125jyxY-OhVR5vul6az-eJ2nZ0PEiOVPqP2KjClaUwAKTBQx5gsIluI0jsGIrpCvNQdUbtKUBxNNH0DH94RHuGpjU29xhTS5Cl8qIgH1MlJHw","event":"registered"}).Please help
```

Answer (score 5):

onNotification must be have scope in window.

```
window.onNotification = function(){

}
```